# Please help me with the following UI formatting

Tags: mysql

Assume the following:

You have a "Doctors" table with the following columns:

FName, LName, Address and DateOfBirth only.

In MySQL script the following such that the output displays:

Full names of all doctors, their addresses, and present age (rounded to 0 decimal places) who were born after 1990-06-30.

The reason I am posting this is that I am doing a UI for a doctor's office and I need this display as one of the outputs. I am stuck on how to nest the sub-query for present age and also how to only list those who are born after a certain date. Can anyone help?

```html
SELECT CONCAT(FName, ' ', LName) AS Student, Address,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, CURRENT_DATE) AS Present_Age
  FROM Student
 WHERE DateOfBirth > (
     SELECT DateOfBirth FROM Student
     WHERE LName='Wiggins' AND FName='Jeanie')
ORDER BY Present_Age DESC;
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: What exactly makes you think that a subquery is required?

Comment: Boss wants it in subqueries instead of joins

Comment: Neither subqueries nor joins are required for your requested output.  Simply use a `WHERE` clause to accomplish the "who were born after 1990-06-30" part and a [date/time function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) such as [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to accomplish the "present age" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you need subqueries or joins for this.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FName, ' ', LName) AS FullName, Address,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, CURRENT_DATE) AS age
  FROM Doctors
 WHERE DateOfBirth > '1990-06-30';
```

See [Date Calculations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-calculations.html) in the MySQL manual for more information.

Comment: What is the type of the `DateOfBirth` field in the table?

Comment: The field type is date and it is not formatted in any special way.

Comment: I don't see why my query doesn't return the desired results then, but you can try casting the column as a date in the `WHERE` clause (i.e. `WHERE DATE(DateOfBirth) > '1990-06-30'`)

Comment: @BenjaminDeMers The above solution is correct. See [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cc99/1).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(FName, ' ', LName) AS Student, Address,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, CURRENT_DATE) AS Present_Age
  FROM Student
 WHERE DateOfBirth > (
     SELECT DateOfBirth FROM Student
     WHERE LName='Wiggins' AND FName='Jeanie')
ORDER BY Present_Age DESC;
```